# Как установить значок для приложения Electron через electron-builder на Linux

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, electron

Никак не получается установить значок для приложения *Linux* через `electron-builder`.
Собираю приложение (`yarn dist`), все собирается, без каких-либо ошибок, запускаю *AppName-1.0.0.AppImage*, но вместо значка просто пустота.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Файл `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
"build": {
    "productName": "AppName",
    "appId": "com.example.appname",
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage",
      "category": "Utility",
      "icon": "icons/256x256.png"
    },
    "files": [
      "src/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets",
      "output": "build"
    }
  }
```

---

Структура проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*electron: 15.0.0

electron-builder: 22.11.7

Ubuntu 20.04*

При этом, когда я просто запускаю *Electron* (`yarn start`), с указанной `icon: __dirname + "/../../assets/icons/64x64.png"` при создании `BrowserWindow`, то значок появляется.

Comment: попробуйте так https://pastebin.com/4D9mxcCN

Comment: @SeniorPomidor При создании deb выскакивает ошибка: `Please specify project homepage, see https://electron.build/configuration/configuration#Metadata-homepage`. Если указать `"homepage": "./",`, то он собирается, при этом в 10 раз дольше. Устанавливаю, иконка появляется, но стандартная от Ubuntu (серая шестеренка на белом фоне).

Comment: палка о двух концах. надо смотреть почему долго собирается.

Comment: [Документация](https://www.electron.build/icons) пишет, что файл `icon.png` или папка `icons` должны находиться в каталоге `build`. В `package.json` их указывать бесполезно.

Comment: @PakUula Все заработало, просто убрал `icon` из `package.json`. В `build` не обязательно перемещать, так же не обязательно паковать в `deb`. Оформите коммент как ответ, чтобы я мог назначить награду. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документация по electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/icons) пишет, что файл icon.png или папка icons должны находиться в каталоге build. В package.json их указывать бесполезно.